# Could not create type 'WebService'

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web-hosting

i have created an one demo webservice
its working ok on my local machine but when i upload it on server i got following error

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WajUB.png) of my error page

please tell me what i am doing wrong

i have uploaded folder that content following items

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqXDq.jpg)

i am new in asp.net please tell me how to upload webservice on server

Comment: [WebService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webservice(v=vs.110).aspx) is a pre-defined class in .net. change the name of your class and try again.

Comment: here are few answers for this type of question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908936/web-service-parser-error-message-could-not-create-type-xxx

Comment: @sebu thanks for your response but i have gone through from all this questions but didn't get solution for my

Comment: How did you deploy the files to your server ? Did you publish it using Publish Wizard in Visual Studio ?

Comment: @Dinny no just i built my project and uploaded it on server

Comment: I am assuming by server you're referring to IIS. Probably you might not have ASP.NET registered in the server. Try registering it. To do it, Open the command prompt as an administrator in your server, and issue a 'cd' command to directory 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319' - Eg., cd 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319'. And then run 'aspnet_regiis.exe - i'